# How can I force require a file in the console? The 'reload!' command just dosen't work!

Tags: ruby, console, reload, require

I use rails-3.0.0.beta3 and ruby-1.9.2-preview3.

I have defined some new methods in the application_controller.rb, and need to test them in the console.

If I changed some codes in the application_controller.rb. 
I have to restart the console.

I have tried to use 'reload!' command, just dosen't work.

And then I use "require 'applicatioin.rb'",
still dosen't work. 

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're in dev mode, then try this:

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
```